# Does Postgres bulk inserts with copy from a query slow the db down?

Tags: postgresql, bulkinsert

So I want to do like an email queue, say 
insert into messages_to_send (email, firstname,lastname, message_text)
select email, firstname,lastname,'hello' from subscribers where list=99

So something like this but say I want to do 100k rows or maybe some day a million. 
Seems like the COPY command would perform better. I don't want to lock the messages_to_send table or slow down the rest of the database. Speed isn't a big issue, I just want it to get in there eventually and another process will pick those up. I'm not that familiar with postgres, maybe COPY is good like that i couldn't tell from reading.

Comment: Maybe I misread COPY, it must be a file or program. I think I just have to do a massive insert from select. Maybe I can put in a cursor and do 10k at a time or so. I don't know what would be safe limits. I'm on Aurora AWS FYI

Comment: So the safe amount of inserts at one time might be 1000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I came up with is to insert 1000 at a time (I saw someone post that was safer), make a table especially for the queue and searching and send to another table after the send. Make sure that table is cleaned out a lot. I suppose if I really want to scale I put that table in a different type of db that postgres, but it should be good for me for now.